# Laravel load pivot data in resource

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I want to show pivot data into json format
I have 2 relationship many to many mode: SubmitForm and Fisherman.

```
// submitform model
public function fisherman()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany(Fisherman::class, 'submitform_fisherman','submitform_id', 'fisherman_id');
}

// fisherman model
public function submitForm()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(SubmitForm::class,'submitform_fisherman','fisherman_id', 'submitform_id');
}
```

this is my submitformcontroller to show the data

```
use App\Http\Resources\SubmitformResource;
use App\SubmitForm;
class SubmitFormController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return SubmitformResource::collection(SubmitForm::with('fisherman')->get());
    }

 ....
}
```

this is my SubmitformResource

```
class SubmitformResource extends JsonResource
{
   public function toArray($request){
    return [
     "id" => $this->id,
     "product_form" => $this->product_form,
     "fisherman" => $this->whenPivotLoaded('submitform_fisherman', function(){
        return new FishermanResource($this->pivot->fisherman);
      })
    }
}
```

when I tried i dont get fisherman data.
Can someone help me?

Comment: what you get? an error? no records?

Comment: i just got json data, but withoud "fisherman" data

Comment: I guess you need to simply $this->fisherman

Comment: it does't work either